Error regarding the version of Snapshot or version
Non-resolvable parent POM for org.pentaho.di:pdi:10.3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: org.pentaho:pentaho-ce-jar-parent-pom:pom:10.3.0.0-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://repo.orl.eng.hitachivantara.com/artifactory/pnt-mvn/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of pentaho-public has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
I want reolve this issue
